# click event not firing on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

My click event is not firing.

My **HTML**:

```
<tr>
    <td>121345</td>
    <!-- Other td-elements -->
    <td><a href = "#" class = "remove-item">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

My **Javascript**:

```
window.document.load = function()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName('remove-item').onClick(function(element)
    {
        console.log("element");
        var productId = element.parentElement.parentElement.childElements[0].value;
        console.log(productId);
    });
};
```

I don't want to use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did some errors there:

- `document.getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements
- `.onClick(...)` is not the way to add an onclick handler

This snippet will remove the parenting `<tr>` element on click of a `Remove`-button:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-item');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
  var item = items[i];
  item.onclick = function(e)
  {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  };
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="remove-item">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="remove-item">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="remove-item">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This helped like this:

`var items = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-item');
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            item.onclick = function(e) {
                productId = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
                console.log(productId);
            };
        }`

Comment: `onclick` isn't really encouraged - use `addEventListener`

Comment: @AndrewLi Why that? Where's the prove?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection elements - not a single one because classes can be applied to multiple elements. From the documentation:

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Just use `[0]` to access the first element in the return array-like object (the first element with that class).

Also `onClick` is not the correct way to add an event handler. You may use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which takes in an event and a handler:

```
window.document.load = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('remove-item')[0].addEventListener("click", function(element) { //add click handler to first element with remove-item class
        console.log("element");
        var productId = element.parentElement.parentElement.childElements[0].value;
        console.log(productId);
    });
}
```

---

If your intention is to apply a click handler to *each* of the elements with the event, you may use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-item');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(currentElement) {
    console.log("element");
    var productId = currentElement.parentElement.parentElement.childElements[0].value;
    console.log(productId);
});
```

`forEach` iterates over each element of the array-like object and for each element (stored in `currentElement`) will execute the callback.

Comment: Better still; loop through the results and add the event handler to each returned element (looks like you have a collection of items that need to be removed). Something like `for( var i in elements ) { ... }`

Comment: `forEach` is cool, but it isn't supported below IE11-- never mind... that's a `Set.prototype.forEach`. Perfectly fine like this ;) Supported IE9 and up

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo Right - edited should work now